# how to create vector mask, or drawing a paths like lasso tool in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, web, draw

how to create tool like [text](https://youtu.be/OzZl3YdmunA?t=205) in flutter web that can drow polylines at the end and return x,y points of edges is there any library code any thing that can help out

create vector mask, or drawing a path with the lasso tool flutter

Comment: simply by using MapPolylineLayer change and update its list by 
** 
int nearestIndex =
          findNearestIndex(ktIterablePolyLinesList ?? [], mapLatLng);
      ktIterablePolyLinesList?.removeAt(nearestIndex);
      ktIterablePolyLinesList?.insert(nearestIndex, mapLatLng);**